# Can I push my working directory without first committing it?

Tags: git

I have my web server set up as a remote git repo, so I can type "git push staging" and my last commit goes live on the server. I used [this tutorial](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) to set this up.

A lot of the time, I'm testing a new feature, and I want to test several iterations of it on the staging server, before it's ready to quality as a commit. Is there a way to push my working directory to the server without having to commit it first?

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible. You can only push changesets (or commits). Thus you always need to create commits.

However, you could create a local development or staging branch where you commit your tests and push them to the server. Once you are satisfied, you can merge+squash /cherry-pick your changes to your master branch.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do **is not possible**, **BUT** your problem can be solved by creating a **feature branch** (a branch where you focus only on implementing a sole feature, that you later merge into master or another branch).

Basically, all you need to do is `git checkout -b feature_branch_name commit_sha1` (where `commit_sha1` is an optional parameter that specifies the starting point of the branch; if you don't specify this parameter it will be HEAD by default).

You keep working (committing & pushing to the main repository):

```
git add .
git commit
git push origin feature_branch_name
# repeat until done
```

and when you finish the feature you merge it in `master` (or whatever other branch you need):

```
git checkout master
git merge feature_branch_name
```

More info on **feature branches** (and branching & merging in general) can be found [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).